# C#. Ошибка при десериализации Xml документа с русскими символами "Invalid character in the given encoding"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

получаю Xml документ, через POST multipart запрос, в приложении на asp net core 2.2
При попытке десериализации документа в Dto объект, возникает исключение, указывающее на ошибку кодировки в строке с русскими символами.

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (8, 15). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 8, position 15.

<StartStation>Красноярск</StartStation>
```

Если Красноярск заменить на Krasnoyarsk то все отработает.

Кодировка в заголовке XML равна "utf-8", менять ее нельзя, т.к. куча клиентов на PHP нормально получают файлы.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tlist>
<t>
<ScheduleId>20905</ScheduleId>
<TrainNumber>6337</TrainNumber>
<TrainType></TrainType>
<StartStation>Красноярск</StartStation>
</t>
</tlist>


[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("tlist")]
public class AdInputType4XmlDtoContainer
{
    [XmlElement("t")]
    public List<AdInputType4XmlDto> Trains { get; set; } = new List<AdInputType4XmlDto>();
}

[Serializable]
public class AdInputType4XmlDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int  ScheduleId { get; set; }                          
    public int TrnId { get; set; }                                 
    public string TrainNumber { get; set; }                        
    public string TrainType { get; set; }                    
    public string DirectionStation  { get; set; }                  
    public string StartStation { get; set; }                        

}


    [HttpPost("SendDataXmlMultipart4Devices")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendDataXmlMultipart4Devices([FromForm] IFormFile username)                                                                      )
    {
        var xmlFile = username;
        try
        {
            if (username.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await xmlFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AdInputType4XmlDtoContainer));
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    var adInputType4XmlList = (AdInputType4XmlDtoContainer)formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream); //!!!! ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "Ошибка в InputDataController/SendDataXmlMultipart4Devices");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А сам файл был сохранен в этой кодировке? Так-то в заголовке можно написать все, что угодно, а файл сохранить иначе.

Comment: Файл формируется динамически java клиентом, PHP сервера с ним работают нормально

Comment: Попробуйте читать файла через XmlReader. Вы его читаете, как обычный файл=> ему пофиг на указанную кодировку в заголовке.

Comment: Какие хедеры и ContentType у входного IFormFile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитал memoryStream через StreamReader с указанием кодировки "Windows-1251".

```
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"), true))
    {
     var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AdInputType4XmlDtoContainer));

    }
```

P.S. по умолчанию net core не нашел эту кодировку у себя, пришлось вызвать в методе Main, для регистрации кодировки для всего WebApi.

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Nuget "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages"
```

Comment: Отсюда следует, что вам приходит xml вовсе не в кодировке utf-8. Поэтому свяжитесь с теми, кто вам шлет эти данные и укажите им на их ошибку. Или исправляйте сами, если это вы делаете...

Comment: Ага значит шлют не то, спасибо за комментарии.